Question regarding witnesses for zina
Is it mandatory to have only "male" witnesses for zina? And for witnesses is there any age limit defined?

when Quran say 4 witness only, then it can be any gender.  Also, if no age limit is specified, any person who can testify can be witness.

Please ask one question per post and search the site for existing answers which cover your queries.

See At what age does a person become an adult in Islam? for the second question.

In opposite to what @Shafeek the Qur'an was very specific in the topic of witnesses, it accepts two female witnesses instead of only one of two male in case of financial topics like debt. But in other cases it didn't make this difference and therefore it is understood that only male witnesses are acceptable. Note that I have asked a question on that topic before.
